# Which is the best character to use as a delimiter for ETL?

Tags: database, format, informix, etl, delimiter

I recently unloaded a customer table from an Informix DB and several rows were rejected because the customer name column contained non-escaped vertical bars (pipe symbol) characters, which is the default DBDELIMITER in the source db. I found out that the field in their customer form has an input mask allowing any alphanumeric character to be entered, which can include any letters, numbers or symbols. So I persuaded the user to run a blanket update on that column to change the pipe symbol to a semicolon. I also discovered other rows containing asterisks and commas in different columns. I could imagine what would happen if this table were to be unloaded in csv format or what damage the asterisks could do!

What is the best character to define as a delimiter? 
If tables are already tainted with pipes, commas, asterisks, tabs, backslashes, etc., what's the best way to clean them up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unload customer table with default pipe; string search for a character that doesn't exist. ie. "~"

unload to file delimiter "~"
select * from customer;

Clean your file (or not) 
(vi replace string):g/theoldstring/s//thenewstring/g)
or
(unix prompt) sed 's/old-char/new-char/g' fileold > filenew

(Once clean id personally change back "~" in unload file to "|" or "," as csv standard)
Load to source db.

Comment: I dont think that's a viable solution, as I have seen tildes after the letter n in several datasets of Spanish and U.S. locales included! As @Brian has pointed out, users can be very creative and enter just about every character imaginable, so best thing is to impose validation on their data input to prevent future contamination, then clean up the exiting mess!

Comment: This, IMHO, is the best and only answer to the question as stated, i.e., use the character that doesn't exist in the data (mine is the second best if you redefine the question as 'character or characters' and can use something besides Informix). If you need to clean your data, then that's a different problem.

Comment: Frank@ You ended with clean up the existing mess. Isn't that the question. And my option was a answer. No wouldn't work if ~ was in the file which is why I stated find a character that isn't. With such there is no flaw to this approach, I use it all the time.

Comment: FWIW, I +1'd your answer.

Answer (score 6):

I have to deal with large volumes of narrative data at my job. This is always a nightmare because users are apt to put ANY character in there, including unprintable characters. You can run a cleanup operation, but you have to do it every time you load data, and it likely won't work forever. Eventually someone will put in what every character you choose as a separator, which is not a problem if your CSV handling libraries can handle escaping properly, but many can't. If this is a one time load/unload, you're probably fine, but if you have to do it more often....

In the past I've changed the separator to the back-tick '`', the tilde '~', or the caret '^'. All failed in the current effort. The best solution I could come up with is to not use CSV format at all. I switched to XML. Even so there were still XML illegal characters, but these can be translated out with atlassian-xml-cleaner-0.1.jar.

Comment: I would like to limit input to letters, numbers and only some symbols, but not the pipe, comma, backslash, asterisk, single and double quotes, as these could cause immediate and future problems. So should I write a routine to prevent users from entering prohibited characters and another routine to scan char and text columns to convert them to something else?

Comment: There are a number of variables involved here. First of all, are your users the ONLY source of data input? If so, you could put your char filtering routine in place FIRST, and then do a one-time clean of all your existing data. That way you don't have to scan and clean every time you extract. If there are other sources of possibly invalid data, you'll probably just have to clean every time you extract.

Comment: Users are not only source of data input. Several feeds, some from IMS on IBM z/OS and other worlds also provide input. It looks like I have to do referential integrity on these feeds and provide them with dirty data reports and my data requirement specs so that they can clean up their mess! I cant think of what would happen if a feed were to contain control characters or a \0 (NULL)?

Comment: Hopefully they are capable/willing to clean up their mess. In the past I did a bunch of Python scripts to deal with this kind of data. One thing you might consider if they won't help you, is a script to convert, say, fixed width files into XML. Then another to convert CSV to XML, etc.... Use XML as your common format. Then run the atlassian-xml-cleaner on these before import.

Comment: Good strategy and advice, I appreciate your suggestions! It ceratinly is unbelievable how much unvalidated dirty data is out there, most of it remaining unchecked for decades!

Comment: Why not escape the delimiters while extracting? XML seems like overkill and unnecessary bloat.

Comment: You can indeed do that if your CSV handling libraries properly recognize escaping/quoting. I've encountered some that don't. In that case, you're stuck basically rolling your own extracts, which is what I did with the Python scripts mentioned above. Agreed about the XML bloat though. Could be a problem if the table is large.

Comment: Given that a lot of input data in the realworld is not properly validated, it seems that unload/load utilities need to be more robust when dealing with problematic data. Rejecting bad rows and logging them when loading helps, but then the keepers of that data need to cleanse it and implement tighter validations to prevent future contamination.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, use a multi-character delimiter. It can still fail, but it should be much more highly unlikely.

Or, escape the delimiter while writing the export file (Informix docs say "LOAD TABLE" escapes by prefixing delimiter characters with backslash). Proper CSV has quoting and escaping so it shouldn't matter if a comma is in the data, unless your exporter and loader cannot handle proper CSV.

Comment: I've never heard of any database that has the ability to import data with multi-character delimiters.

Comment: @Frank - Oracle's sqlplus, Sybase's bcp ... we use them daily ... what have you used? Informix is a good database, are you sure you've checked the docs?

Comment: @Frank - It's been awaile since I worked w/Informix...maybe 'load from file' does not allow it...but at least it allows escaping delimiters in the data, which Sybase's bcp does not. I can't believe Informix would not let you do this...what about Informix's other bulk loading utilities?

Comment: AFAICR, None of the Informix versions with DBLOAD, HPL or other utilities and built-in SQL statements allow more than one DBDELIMITER character.

Comment: In my circumstance, it would be better to have the source data cleansed before unloading it. Then I wouldn't have to roll a cleansing utility which could be risky.

Comment: "it would be better to have the source data cleansed..." - then why are you asking what the best delimiter is? As I said, the best delimiter is a multi-character one (sorry it doesn't work for you), or escape the delimiter as you write out the data, or use some odd control characters as delimiters. I've never had to fall back to quoted-CSV or XML.

Comment: My formerly high opinion of Informix has just gone down a notch :-( Both Oracle and Sybase can handle this simple requirement, why not Informix?